# how to redirect naked domains in apache to www

Tags: apache-2.2, web, .htaccess, redirect

i have multiple naked domains and i want to redirect those domains so that they begin with www.redirecteddomain.com.
i have this .htaccess file which works with on domain how to generalize this ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guvam\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.guvam.com$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't quite understand the question, but you want it to work for any domain to direct to the *www.* version?

This should work for that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this slightly more readable

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```